# Moving div, using Jquery produce strange result

Tags: jquery, css

I have this very simple Jquery script and Im trying to make a moving side banner. The problem is while it moves as should be as showed in the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2392/

But once I put it in the actual page, on load of page the inner content "disappears" in upper left corner of wrapper div.

here is my code of the actual page:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#slideout {
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 45%;
    right:-280px;
    padding-left: 300px
}
    
#clickme {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #000000;
}

#slidecontent {
    float:right;
}
#content {
    background: #000000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        <div id="content">
            hi
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});

</script>



<style>
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#slideout {
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 45%;
    right:-280px;
    padding-left: 300px
}

#clickme {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #000000;
}

#slidecontent {
    float:right;
}
#content {
    background: #000000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>


<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        <div id="content">
            hi
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's hard to find out the problem without your "actual page code" ... the code in the fiddle just need some minnor CSS changes http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2404/

Comment: Thats the thing, Id does work fine in fiddle but it fails in html page. I dont have anything else than that code abowe.

Comment: If your code is exactly the same as the one in the question (and in the fiddle), then your problem is not in your code.

Comment: Where should I look for a problem? The page is simple php, there is nothing there.

Comment: I really can't say with no more code ... and I hate PHP :)